# Application launches from release folder, but does not launch from program files folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022

I am using windows 10 and VS 2022.  I can not launch the application from the program files folder, but I can launch the application from the release folder from the build.

I copied the application from the build folder to program files folder.  The application does not run.  I created a shortcut on my desktop to the application on the build folder - that works.  I scanned with my virus checker, no issues detected.

Comment: If you don't know why your program failed then you need to work on that first.  Writing an event handler for AppDomain.UnhandledException is not really optional.

Comment: There is presumably some dependency missing. If you copy the entire output folder contents elsewhere, does it work then?

Comment: Check your Windows Event log for .NET Application errors.

Comment: I did fix the error.  No change. I have tried using primary output and the exe.  No change.

Comment: I copied the contents to another folder.  It did not work.  This a simple application.  Only files in the folder are the exe and the icon.

Comment: I do not see how this may matter but..  The application was written in a much older version of Visual studio.  2003 if my memory is correct.  I created a new solution, opened the code in notepad and did a copy and paste.  I did not use add existing.

Comment: You are correct.  I copied all the files from the build folder to the folder used by the shortcut and now it works.  I just need to figure out how to fix the setup project..  Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I copied all the files from the build folder to the folder used by the shortcut and now it works. I just need to figure out how to fix the setup project.

Answer (score 0):

I added the Primary output to the setup project.  The build now creates all the necessary files (.dll and the .runtimeconfig) in the folder.  I also included the .exe in the project and pointed the shortcut to the .exe.

Answer (score -1):

maybe this is because the release folder contain some dll files that dynamicly linked with your application

Comment: An answer that starts with 'maybe' isn't an answer.